# Add a pkcs#11 certificate into a keystore object with setCertificateEntry(cert) fails

Tags: java, keystore, smartcard, pkcs#11

## Note

I don't want to import a certificate into a keystore with `keytool`. What I want, is to add a `java.security.cert.Certificate` object into a `java.security.KeyStore` object.

## Scenario

My apps works with FireFox user certificates and those in a smartcard, with NSS + JSS. The APP first loads all user certificates via NSS and stores them into a `KeyStore` object, and stores their SN, DN, etc. Then, with `org.mozilla.jss.CryptoManager` I load all external modules, then every token of the modules, at last, with this line, I get a `CryptoStore` with all certificates of the token:

```
CryptoStore store = null;
store = token.getCryptoStore();
org.mozilla.jss.crypto.X509Certificate[] certs = store.getCertificates();
```

Then, I read these certificates and store their SN, DN, etc., along with those data of user certificates, for UI part to show.

When doing an authentication, the user is prompted a dialog with all certificates to choose. This window has a table with rows containing `alias` of each certificate, users' + card. Then I pick the certificate from the `keyStore` with the selected `alias`.

## Error

Here comes the problem: the `keyStore` only has entries of user certificates from FireFox, not those in the card. If I pick one from the card, and do this:

```
certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
```

It returns `null`. It makes sense because those from the card are stored in `CryptoStore`. Now, if I do this:

```
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert); //cert is a certificate from card
```

no exception occurs. Then, when I do this again:

```
certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
```

A `NullPointerException` from `sun.security.pkcs11.p11keyStore.P11KeyStore.getID()` happens.

## Question

- Adding a certificate from a smartcard to a `java.security.KeyStore` is possible with my approach here?
- Why the exception?

Comment: When using PKCS keystore type I also faced the same problem. Basically the solution for me was using a JKS keystore type.